# Hibernate return object with annotation

Tags: web-services, hibernate

I'm trying to create a webservice.

I have a class UserVO with Hibernate annotations with the attributes login, password and id.

I need to return the object but with those annotations I have this error:

```
Service invocation threw an exception with message : null; Refer to the server log for more details

Exceptions details : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

But if I take the annotations, things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you expose objects as a webservice the protocol cannot create the definitions for annotations...

I'd strongly recommend you to create a set of data transfer objects which can be converted into your hibernate model and back... this would simplify your design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm gonna try that on monday and report back with results, thanks again.